# How to return an array of non duplicate strings without using Streams or Hashsets

Tags: java

I wanted to create a function which has the following protoype:

```
   public static String[] removeDuplicates(String [] strings)
```

This function is supposed to take an array of strings and return another array of strings without duplicate strings. I am trying not to use Streams or Hashset as this is supposed to be a not so advanced exercise and I should only use Arrays. I would also like to do this allocating as little memory as possible, not creating many copies of the array.
The obvious solution which comes to mind is having a copy of the array where I'll add strings to it if they're not already there. However, that involves iterating over an array to see if it's already there and also creating a new copy to return because I probably allocated more space than was occupied on the array. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't allowed streams, or sets or other auxiliary data structures, then the "obvious" solution is pretty much all you can do; but sorting the array first will make it more efficient, since then duplicates will always appear next to each other.

Note that you'll need to do two passes, first to count the distinct elements, and then to put the distinct elements into a result array. You won't be able to allocate the result array before knowing how long it should be.

Answer (score 2):

> How to return an array of non duplicate strings without using Streams
> or Hashsets

You can use an `ArrayList` for this purpose. While iterating the array of strings, simply check if the string is already present in the list; if not, add it to the list. Finally, convert the list to an array and return the same.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(removeDuplicates(new String[] { "Hello", "Hi", "Bye", "Hello", "Hi" })));
    }

    public static String[] removeDuplicates(String[] strings) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : strings) {
            if (!list.contains(s)) {
                list.add(s);
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Hello, Hi, Bye]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you must use arrays and not Lists, Maps or any form of collections. So here is a simple approach.

Just check to see if the result array contains the current string.  If it doesn't add it, else continue to the next string. Then at the end, copy the result to itself to eliminate the null values.

```
String[] a = {"A","E","B","A","C","D","C","E","A"};

int rcount = 0;
String[] result = new String[a.length];

outer:
for (String i : a) {
    for (int k = 0; k < rcount; k++) {
        if (i.equals(result[k])) {
            continue outer;
        }
    }
    result[rcount++] = i;
}
//  now copy only the strings and reduce the size of the array.
result = Arrays.copyOf(result, rcount);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result))
```

Prints

```
[A, E, B, C, D]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, your best bet to avoid poor performance is to sort the array and look at adjacent entries for duplicates, acquiring the result array in two passes. Something along these lines:

```
public static String[] removeDuplicates(String[] strings) {
    Arrays.sort(strings);
    List<String> uniqueStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        String currentString = strings[i];
        uniqueStrings.add(currentString);
        i++;
        while (i < strings.length && currentString.equals(strings[i])) {
            i++;
        }
        i--;
    }
    return uniqueStrings.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```